# bootstrap 4 button group responsive

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Good day,

I have a little issue with bootstrap button groups. Probably I am doing something wrong or I am overlooking something. But I am running a bit at a dead end here. So I hope that someone could shed a bit of light on this topic.

I have a couple of buttons set inside of a bootstrap group.
The buttons are nicely aligned and appear as they should.
Except for mobile.

When I resize the window however I notice that the buttons stay horizontally aligned. They do not automatically form a row such as bootstrap columns.

Now this is exactly what I would like. Since I want those buttons to form a toolbar that is usable on a mobile phone as well.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="btn-group mr-2" role="group" aria-label="button group">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">button one</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">button two</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">button three</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">button four</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">button five</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">button six</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Take the code above.

That generates the following :

[image: Buttons well aligned]

But when resizing the thing I get :

[image: Scrolling horizontally is evil!]

Whilst I would like the buttons to resize or order in a way they are suitable as a toolbar functioning for mobile phones.

Comment: Please clarify exactly what behavior you expect on mobile. Do you expect the buttons do become smaller? Stack vertically into a column?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you see is the default behavior of the button-group class... so we can define our own rule for the width breakpoint where the scroll starts to emerge by adding the following CSS:

```
@media screen and (max-width:576px){
.btn-group{display:flex;    flex-direction: column;}
}
```

Complete **snippet** below:

```css
@media screen and (max-width:576px) {
  .btn-group {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="btn-group mr-2 " role="group" aria-label="button group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">button one</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">button two</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">button three</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">button four</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">button five</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">button six</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to actually size the buttons inside your container grid.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/layout/grid/

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="btn-group row" role="group" aria-label="button group">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default col-md-2">button one</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default col-md-2">button two</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default col-md-2">button three</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default col-md-2">button four</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default col-md-2">button five</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default col-md-2">button six</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. This makes it follow bootstrap guidelines without adding extra css